# How do I properly use SDL_GL_BindTexture()?

Tags: c, opengl, sdl-2

Calling SDL_GL_BindTexture() returns "That operation is not supported".
The documentation states that I would need an "implicit OpenGL context from SDL_CreateRenderer()" (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_GL_BindTexture) but it explains nowhere how to get a context from SDL_CreateRenderer(). I do not know if that is what causes the error but it is the only thing I found.

I am using SDL2 with OpenGL. I created a context using SDL_GL_CreateContext().
Drawing is working just fine but binding a SDL_Texture using SDL_GL_BindTexture() returns "That operation is not supported".
I created the window using the SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL flag and the renderer without the SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED flag.
The texture is created using IMG_LoadTexture() from SDL2_image.

Comment: I would just avoid this function. The "implicit context" thing sounds like a pain in the butt. Manually creating a texture isn't hard. I'd recommend `stb_image` if you need something simple to load the pixel data.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat since OP is already using SDL they can use IMG_Load from the SDL_Image library.

Comment: @SafelyFast Is a tiny bit harder, since you have to deal with different surface formats and row padding, while `stb_image` outputs in fixed format and no padding.